# Is there a way to render the page my script is on when I manually cancel the script in phantomjs?

Tags: phantomjs

So like the title says, is there a way to render a png of the page my script is on if a error codes to causes the code to run an infinite loop when I manually stop the code in terminal with CTRL+C in phantomJS?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have that much control over the PhantomJS process. The only event handler that looks promising is [`phantom.onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/handler/on-error.html) and it doesn't work with it (I just tried it).